# Why won't this loop produce my desired result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Desired result :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

My loop:

```
arr = []
n = 0; b = 0
while b < 2
  while n < 12
    arr.push n
    n++
  b++
return arr
```

Actual result :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: You could also just use `[1..12].concat [1..12]`

Comment: Ah I didn't know JS support that. Fantastic thanks!

Comment: Or technically `([1,2,3]+","+[1,2,3]).split(",")`, but it's probably not the most efficient, and isn't safe with arrays that contain strings (that possibly hold "," characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reinitialize the value of `n` to 0 after being done with it in the inner loop:

```
arr = []
n = 0; b = 0
while b < 2
  while n < 12
    arr.push n
    n++
  n = 0         // <------ Added this
  b++
return arr
```

That way, each outer iteration has a "fresh" value of `n`.

Although with this, I'm getting the values 0 to 11, not 1 to 12 as you think. So I would modify it to this (with real JS):

```
function test() {
    var arr = [];
    var n = 1;
    var b = 0;
    while (b < 2) {
        while (n <= 12) {
            arr.push(n);
            n++;
        }
        n = 1;
        b++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But as @Blender has pointed out, since you're really just emulating a `for` loop, use one!:

```
function test2() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
        for (var n = 1; n <= 12; n++) {
            arr.push(n);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You could also just use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Blender Absolutely, I was just trying to point out the immediate problem. Post the answer quickly, then explanation follows :)